# IOmniTaskControl.Unobserved - the task is never destroyed

Tags: multithreading, delphi, omnithreadlibrary

I am trying to run a fire-and-forget task - `IOmniTaskControl.Unobserved` works well enough with either `IOmniTaskControl.Run` or `IOmniTaskControl.Schedule(IOmniThreadPool)`, but the `IOmniTaskControl` object is never destroyed.

I am limited to using `Unobserved` since I have an arbitrary number of tasks and I do not want to store them in a dedicated variable or a list - removing a task from that list would be a hustle in itself since it can only be done from the task body.

Am I missing something? I thought that `IOmniTaskControl.Unobserved` will destroy itself after it runs.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've never answered my own question that quickly :-)

`TOmniTaskControl` is destructed from the `TOmniEventMonitor.WndProc` window proc, which of course only runs if there is a message loop in the thread where the monitor was created by the task. In my case, the tasks were created from a dedicated thread (I used `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread`). Adding a message loop to my thread proc (which runs an infinite while loop) fixed the problem:

```
  //Omni thread library uses Windows messages to communicate with itself
  while PeekMessage(wMsg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE or PM_NOYIELD) do begin
    TranslateMessage(wMsg);
    DispatchMessage(wMsg)
  end;
```